# ggplot2: Plotting on a grid with fewer plots than viewports

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra, gtable

```
library( ggplot2 )
library( gridExtra )
p1 <- qplot( rnorm( 10 ), rnorm( 10 ) )
p2 <- qplot( rnorm( 10 ), rnorm( 10 ) )
p3 <- qplot( rnorm( 10 ), rnorm( 10 ) )
p4 <- qplot( rnorm( 10 ), rnorm( 10 ) )
p5 <- qplot( rnorm( 10 ), rnorm( 10 ) )
grid.arrange( p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, nrow=2 )
```

I would like to center the bottom two plots. How can do this? I can do it using `split.screen` but I'm unable to figure out how to do this with `ggplot2`. `ggplot2` has cooler graphics.

Thanks in advance!

PK

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use the `gtable` package for flexible and convenient grid layouts, or simply nest two arrangeGrobs,

```
ng = nullGrob()
grid.arrange(arrangeGrob(p1, p2, p3, nrow=1),
             arrangeGrob(ng, p4, p5, ng, nrow=1, widths=c(0.5, 1, 1, 0.5)),
             nrow=2)
```

[image]

---

*Edit:*  For the bottom plots to span the full width, you simply need to remove the dummy nullGrobs() in the above solution:

```
grid.arrange(arrangeGrob(p1, p2, p3, nrow=1),
             arrangeGrob(p4, p5, nrow=1),
             nrow=2)
```

[image]

Comment: Loved the answer but would be interested in seeing the `gtable` answer you discussed as well. +1

Comment: Thanks. What would be better was if the bottom plots filled the space.

Answer (score 7):

Here's an alternative way using `gtable`:

```
library(gtable)
gtable_add_grobs <- gtable_add_grob #misleading name

g <- gtable(widths = unit(rep(1, 6), "null"), # need lcm(3,2)=6 for the matrix rows
            heights = unit(rep(1, 2), "null"))

#gtable_show_layout(g)

g <- gtable_add_grobs(g, lapply(list(p1, p2, p3, p4, p5), ggplotGrob),
                     t = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2),
                     l = c(1, 3, 5, 2, 4),
                     r = c(2, 4, 6, 3, 5))

grid.newpage()
grid.draw(g)
```

Edit: For the bottom plots to span the full width, you simply need to alter the corresponding l and r indices,

```
g <- gtable_add_grobs(g, lapply(list(p1, p2, p3, p4, p5), ggplotGrob),
                      t = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2),
                      l = c(1, 3, 5, 1, 4),
                      r = c(2, 4, 6, 3, 6))
```